# Best practices for Indexing an array in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

When the base address of an array is stored in a register, it is my understanding that one does not want to adjust that register.  I am trying to understand when that principle is valid.  Is this a valid practice when dealing with saved registers only or saved registers and argument registers, too?

Below is a an example I am working that involves converting simple C code into MIPS instruction.  I attempted the solution in two ways.

In the first solution, I increment the registers that were originally holding the base address of array a and array b.  My thoughts were that the given base address registers, $a0 and $a1, are argument registers, not saved registers.  I thought, perhaps, it wouldn't matter that they were adjusted.  In my second solution, I stored the base address of each array into temporary registers and manipulated those instead.

I did find some solutions online to this particular example, but I'm trying to understand the basis for each instruction, rather than just following a procedural solution.  Any advice on best MIPS practice is greatly appreciated!

```
# C Code:
for (i=0; i<=100; i=i+1) 
{ 
    a[i] = b[i] + c; 
}

# $a0 = base address of array a
# $a1 = base address of array b
# $s0 = c

# Attempted Solution # 1

li      $t0, 0                  # t0 = 0
li      $t1, 101                # t1 = 100

Loop:
lw      $t2, 0($a1)             # t2 = b[i]
add     $t3, $t2, $s0           # t3 = b[i] + c 
sw      $t3, 0($a0)             # a[i] = b[i] + c
addi    $a0, $a0, 4             # a0 = address of a[i+1]
add     $a1, $a1, 4             # a1 = address of b[i+1]
addi    $t0, 1                  # t0 = i++
bne     $t0, $t1, Loop          # If t0 != 101, loop again.

# Attempted Solution # 2:

li      $t0, 0                  # t0 = 0
li      $t1, 101                # t1 = 100
add     $t2, $a0, $zero         # t2 = adress of a[0]
add     $t3, $a1, $zero         # t3 = adress of b[0]

Loop:
lw      $t4, 0($t3)             # t4 = b[i]
add     $t4, $t4, $s0           # t4 = b[i] + c 
sw      $t4, 0(t2)              # a[i] = b[i] + c 
addi    $t2, $t2, 4             # t2 = address of a[i+1]
addi    $t3, $t3, 4             # t3 = address of b[i+1]
bne     $t0, $t1, Loop          # If t0 != 101, loop again.
```

Comment: Nothing against changing the argument registers if you do not need their original content later.

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to print the contents of that array a from beginning to end, I'd either have to keep the address of a[0] or bring my current address all the way back there by, I suppose, subtraction?

Comment: You'd need to do one or the other. While the `$a` registers are not saved registers, if you want to save them on the stack and recall them later there's nothing wrong with doing that. Or better yet, just copy `$a0` and `$a1` to `$a2` and `$a3`. It's always faster to copy a register to another register than it is to store a register into RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *converting* C code to assembly (i.e. manually compiling) then you have to make sure that no information is lost.

If the only "copy" of the base address of arrays a and b are stored in `$a0` and `$a1` and you them after your for loop then you should preserve them. If those addresses are preserved elsewhere you may modify them if you are not going to use them later in your routine.

For example, suppose your C code does something else with arrays a or b after the for loop, e.g:

```
for (i=0; i<=100; i=i+1) 
{ 
    a[i] = b[i] + c; 
}

c = a[0]
```

then you either preserve the base address of array a or you recalculate it after the for loop.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!  I'm moving onto functions next, so this will be helpful.  Cheers!